# SQL check for NULLs in WHERE clause (ternary operator?)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

What would the SQL equivalent to this C# statement be?

`bool isInPast = (x != null ? x < DateTime.Now() : true)`

I need to construct a `WHERE` clause that checks that `x < NOW()` only if `x IS NOT NULL`. `x` is a `datetime` that needs to be null sometimes, and not null other times, and I only want the `WHERE` clause to consider non-null values, and consider null values to be true.

Right now the clause is:

`dbo.assignments.[end] < { fn NOW() }`

Which works for the non-NULL cases, but NULL values always seem to make the expression evaluate to false. I tried:

`dbo.assignments.[end] IS NOT NULL AND dbo.assignments.[end] < { fn NOW() }`

And that seems to have no effect.

Comment: Never mind, it was a problem with my data.

Answer (score 5):

For use in a WHERE clause, you have to test separately

```
where dbo.assignments.[end] is null or dbo.assignments.[end] < GetDate()
```

or you can turn the nulls into a date (that will always be true)

```
where isnull(dbo.assignments.[end],0) < GetDate()
```

or you can do the negative test against the bit flag derived from the below

```
where case when dbo.assignments.[end] < GetDate() then 0 else 1 end = 1
```

---

The below is explanation and how you would derive isInPast for a SELECT clause.

> bool isInPast = (x != null ? x < DateTime.Now() : true)

A bool can only have one of two results, true or false.
Looking closely at your criteria, the **ONLY condition for false** is when

> x != null && x < now

Given that fact, it becomes an easy translation, given that in SQL, `x < now` can only be evaluated when `x!=null`, so **only one condition** is needed

```
isInPast = case when dbo.assignments.[end] < { fn NOW() } then 0 else 1 end
```

(1 being true and 0 being false)

Not sure what `{ fn NOW() }` represents, but if want SQL Server to provide the current time, use either GETDATE() or if you are working with UTC data, use GETUTCDATE()

```
isInPast = case when dbo.assignments.[end] < GetDate() then 0 else 1 end
```

Answer (score 0):

The one you are looking for is probably the [CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) statement

Answer (score 0):

You need something like

```
WHERE X IS NULL
OR X < NOW()
```

Comment: I think you mean `GetDate()` instead of `Now()` for SQL Server.

Comment: Yes, that is true, just keeping it the same as the OP question

Answer (score 0):

Have two separate queries, one when x is null one when is not. Trying to mix the two distinct conditions is the sure shot guaranteed way to get a bad plan. Remember that the generated plan must work for *all* values of x, so any optimization based on it (a range scan on an index) is no longer possible.